# when doing a WalkDir of a FileSystem, how do you get access to the path that you are working on

Tags: go

I'm using the reasonably new FileSystem style to do the usual directory walk
processing every file in the usual recursive manner.
I can't figure out how to get the directory data (the path up to the last /)
even though I can see it in the output.

I am missing the proper name of the getter, or perhaps a cast/type assertion

Playground:
https://go.dev/play/p/Fde-rAA5YZI

The key code is

```
fsys := os.DirFS(".")
fs.WalkDir(fsys, ".", func(p string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        fmt.Printf("%s  struct: %T  %v\n", p, d, d)
```

which prints "'p" the current file name and extension
the type of the fs.DirEntry and then the fsDirEntry structure

Something like this:

```
csvtsd/csvtsd.go  struct: *os.unixDirent  &{../csvtsd csvtsd.go 0 <nil>}
csvtsd/csvtsd_test.go  struct: *os.unixDirent  &{../csvtsd csvtsd_test.go 0 <nil>}
csvtsd/go.mod  struct: *os.unixDirent  &{../csvtsd go.mod 0 <nil>}
```

You can see that the "p" is typically the path and filename: csvtsd/csvtsd.go
the type is a  *os.unixDirent
and there are four fields in the Dirent, the path (up to the last /)
the filename and extension, and two other fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is not method to get the directory name from the [DirEntry](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#DirEntry)

Use [path.Dir](https://godoc.org/path#Dir) to get the directory from the path argument to the [walk function](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#WalkDirFunc):

```
fsys := os.DirFS(".")
fs.WalkDir(fsys, ".", func(p string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
     fmt.Printf("dir=%s, path=%s\n", path.Dir(p), p)
     return nil
})
```